# dereferencing hash from params

Tags: perl, hash, dereference

This code works:

```
  my $href = shift @_;    # get reference to hash
  my %h = %{$href};       # dereference hash
```

This one does not:

```
  my %h = %{shift @_};
```

As well as this one:

```
  my %h = ${$_[0]}
```

Why?

## =============================

One more time to be precisly:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
  2 use strict;
  3 use warnings;
  4 
  5 my %h;
  6 sub a {
  7     
  8     # that works - result 1
  9     my $href = $_[0] || shift;
 10     %h = %{$href};
 11     
 12     # that does not work - result 0
 13     # my %h = %{$_[0]};
 14     
 15     # as well as that one - result 0
 16     # my %h = %{shift @_};
 17     $h{1}=2;
 18 }
 19 
 20 a(\%h);
 21 print scalar (keys %h) . "\n";
```

In other words line 16 - it doesn't.

Comment: I updated my answer, your problem is totally unrelated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work.

```
  my %h = %{shift @_};
```

This won't.

```
  my %h = ${$_[0]} # not ${$_[0]}
```

That sigil is supposed to be `%`

```
  my %h = %{$_[0]}
```

also, `use warnings;`, and `use strict;`

---

***HINT:*** The reason your above example doesn't work, is only one example doesn't declare a lexical variable `%h = %{$href};` is not `my %h = %{$href};`

Comment: Does anyone not use warnings and strict?

Comment: @demosthenex: yes, lots of people unfortunately.